# How does Unsafe#freeMemory know how much memory to deallocate in Java?

Tags: java, unsafe

The `Unsafe#freeMemory` doesn't take arguments the memory it need to free.

Comment: The `freeMemory` takes the address of the native heap node to be freed as an argument.  The node's header has the information needed to do the deallocation.